# Using Mongo aggregates in Meteor

Tags: typescript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I need to use Mongo's `$lookup` operator to add some related data to a Meteor collection, so I've installed `tunguska:reactive-aggregate` package from AtmosphereJs (https://atmospherejs.com/tunguska/reactive-aggregate). Following its documentation, this is how I use it:

```js
import { ReactiveAggregate } from 'meteor/tunguska:reactive-aggregate';

Meteor.publish("orders", function () {
  ReactiveAggregate(this, OrdersCollection, [{
    $lookup: {
      from: "customers",
      localField: "customer_id",
      foreignField: "wooCommerce_id",
      as: "customerInfo"
    }
  }]);
})
```

It works, and I get the customer's information in the `customerInfo` field of the collection. However, the Typescript compiler complains with this error:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module "meteor/tunguska:reactive-aggregate"`

Is there any way to fix this error? I think it's a matter of adding this package to the list of "detected" ones, just like when you import `meteor/check`, for example, but I don't know how to do it. The app works as expected, but I don't like having marked files in the IDE when there should be no error...

Thanks!

Comment: Typescript is looking for a typings file, you can probably create this by hand

Comment: Hi, I think that the problem is, besides that there are no typings, that it can't find any module with that name in any folder monitored by the compiler. I've checked both the local `npm_modules` and the Meteor one (`.meteor/local/build/programs/server/npm/node_modules`) and I couldn't find anything about the package...

Comment: Meteor packages are not in `node_modules` directory. You need to check the `.meteor/packages` for the package name or run `meteor add tunguska:reactive-aggregate` to ensure that the package is present. Also you should start Meteor project via Meteor `meteor run`.

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the Meteor project folder structure, I think I understand what's going on:

- As explained in the comments above, Meteor packages are not in `node_modules`, but in `.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages`. It seems that Meteor bundles this packages when compiling the application, so it works when you import and use some of them, like:

```js
import { ReactiveAggregate } from 'meteor/tunguska:reactive-aggregate';

Meteor.publish("orders", function () {
  ReactiveAggregate(this, OrdersCollection, [{
     ...
  }]);
});
```

The only problem with this is that the IDE complains that it can't find the module, so to fix it we need to add a typings file. As there isn't any, I'll try to create one when I have more free time.

Cheers!